# Is it possible to have a user license added to a sandbox instead of having to inherit from Production?

Tags: licenses, userlicense

Let's say I want a new user license type added to a specific sandbox. Is that something that can be done by Salesforce or must the sandbox inherit the user license types from Production?

It seems that it can only inherit it from Production but that seems strange as there must surely be important use cases where a user type does NOT get added first to Production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you want to test the license type for a limited-time proof of concept, Salesforce will only provision the license in production, then you have to click the Match Production Licenses button in the sandbox.  That is their policy.